# 'Invalid hostname' response from http.sys

Tags: http, bad-request, http.sys

We have web service running hosted on an OwinHttpListener (http.sys behind the scenes). Whenever we send requests to the app on the IP address, it responds with 'Invalid hostname'.

After much trawling of stack overflow and google, im not really any closer to a solution. The requests are getting through to http.sys, as i can see them in the HTTP error log. I can log onto the server in question and access the service locally (using localhost or 127.0.0.1) and i can use the server name to successfully get through, the only failure condition is using the servers IP address.

Ive tried the following:

- Ensure the app is listening on all interfaces (http://+:8080)
- Ensure IIS is not trying to use the port (it isnt)
- Ensure windows firewall is configured to allow traffic on that port (it is)

Comment: Does it work with `http://*:8080` ?

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Comment: try putting a trace on http.sys   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace/

Comment: What are you putting in the host header?  Also is this invalid hostname coming back from the server as an HTTP error response, or is it being generated by the app itself?  If the latter, you could possibly try putting in a host file entry so you can still refer to the target server by a name that needs to be resolved.